# How to verify text with breaks using webriver

Tags: java, selenium

I have the below HTML, and want to verify the text.

```
<span id="ctl00_cphMainContent_lblWelcomeText" class="firefinder-match">
    We each spend a lot of energy on work – being here each day and often thinking about it when we’re not. So it’s to our benefit to create a work environment that is healthy and energizing … and where we can be “at our best.” When we’re at our best, we have better thinking. We’re more creative, more innovative, and it shows in our performance as individuals and collectively as an enterprise … it helps us have the best possible results. 
    <br>
    <br>
    We need your honest feedback. Be confident that your responses will be anonymous – all data goes directly to our external survey partner, Kenexa, and cannot be associated with any specific person, by me or anyone else here. The survey is the first step in the process … next we’ll work in teams to make real change happen, based on your feedback. 
    <br>
    <br>
    Thank you for taking the survey … for making the commitment. Feedback matters and we each can influence our work environment. We all share responsibility for it.
</span>
```

Here is the code I am using, but I keep getting failures saying that the text does not match. I am using \n\n where the breaks occur. I also tried using \r\n\r\n where the breaks occur, but I get the same result. Can anyone help me identify what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

```
String actualtext = driver.getSingleElement("css=span#ctl00_cphMainContent_lblWelcomeText").getText();
    Assert.assertEquals(actualtext, "We each spend a lot of energy on work – being here each day and often thinking about it when we’re not. So it’s to our benefit to create a work environment that is healthy and energizing … and where we can be “at our best.” When we’re at our best, we have better thinking. We’re more creative, more innovative, and it shows in our performance as individuals and collectively as an enterprise … it helps us have the best possible results.\n\nWe need your honest feedback. Be confident that your responses will be anonymous – all data goes directly to our external survey partner, Kenexa, and cannot be associated with any specific person, by me or anyone else here. The survey is the first step in the process … next we’ll work in teams to make real change happen, based on your feedback.\n\nThank you for taking the survey … for making the commitment. Feedback matters and we each can influence our work environment. We all share responsibility for it.");
```

When I print actualtext, it has the breaks.

> We each spend a lot of energy on work – being here each day and often
>   thinking about it when we’re not. So it’s to our benefit to create a
>   work environment that is healthy and energizing … and where we can be
>   “at our best.” When we’re at our best, we have better thinking. We’re
>   more creative, more innovative, and it shows in our performance as
>   individuals and collectively as an enterprise … it helps us have the
>   best possible results.
>
> We need your honest feedback. Be confident that your responses will be
>   anonymous – all data goes directly to our external survey partner,
>   Kenexa, and cannot be associated with any specific person, by me or
>   anyone else here. The survey is the first step in the process … next
>   we’ll work in teams to make real change happen, based on your
>   feedback.
>
> Thank you for taking the survey … for making the commitment. Feedback
>   matters and we each can influence our work environment. We all share
>   responsibility for it.

I am not sure why this question warrants a -1. If more information is
needed, please let me know. I'm relatively new to this

Comment: have you checked what the value of `actualText` is after the first line?

Comment: +1 @desbo - I think the OP's got some embedded blanks following those newlines.

Comment: The issue I was having was that there was a blank space after one of the lines that I wasn't accounting for. Once I added the blank space, my test worked. I also removed all white spaces by using the below code, and that worked as well.

`textA = textA.replaceAll("\\s","");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `getText()` just escapes the break tags and does not change them to `\n`. The first thing you should have done was to print `actualtext`.

EDIT: sorry, I was wrong about `getText()`

Comment: I did print `actualtext`. It had breaks, so thats why I thought I would need \n\n

Comment: maybe you're using a Mac? have you tried `\r` ? Or `System.lineSeparator()` ? You can also try to compare the strings character by character to find out where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not using a Mac, and have not tried \r. I've compared the strings character by character and don't see any difference, which is why I'm stuck. I'm not sure what else to check for.

Comment: I didn't mean to literally compare by looking at the text but to run a for loop and check the equality of each character in those strings. Or  just debug the test in your IDE and check what happens in `assertEquals`